How to Set Datetime as x-axis in ax.contourf plots?
I am trying to visualize space weather indices as contour filled plots with date on x-axis and hour on y-axis and value as dst.
So far I have created the following plots successfully using my code:
NOTE: dst is a pivot table created from the dataset given in the link:  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cz5i2n6zGGsQVDejRpteai8Zs07_58vL/view?usp=sharing
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2, figsize=(8,5), )

ct = axes[0].contourf(dst, cmap="coolwarm_r", extend="both", )
ct_kp = axes[1].contourf(kp, cmap="coolwarm", extend = "both")

add_colorbar(fig, axes[0], ct, "nT")
add_colorbar(fig, axes[1], ct_kp, "kp")

for ax in axes:
    ax.set_ylabel("Hour")
    ax.axvline(30, color="black", linestyle="--")

axes[1].set_xticklabels(["-30", "-25", "-20", "-15", "-10", "-5", "EQ", "5", "10", "15"]);
axes[1].set_xlabel("Days")

fig.tight_layout()


Now I want to set the date on x axis with 5 day gap between each major tick but unable to do so.
Here's what I've tried so far!
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
ax.set_xticks(dst.columns)

But for some reasons I am getting the following figure:

